# Only first pdf file filled with fpdm can be opened

Tags: php, pdf

this is my first question here so please excuse if this is incomprehensible.

I've got a little web tool on PHP for registering examinees to an examination. At the end I want to fill a PDF form  with FPDM with data from the database in a foreach. The frist file which is created is perfect. The others are created but when I want to open with Acrobat or Chrome the loading is failed. I can fill every set of data separately but when I call the filling function twice or multiple times, the second file can not be opened.
MS Edge is able to open the currupt files but doesn't show the fonts correctly. So FPDM seems to fill all forms correctly but the files are somehow broken.

I'm searching for solutiones sincs days but no idea where is the problem. The code should be correct.
Can anybody help??

Here is the code:

```
require_once('libs/fpdm.php');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `examinations` WHERE uid = :uid");
$result = $statement->execute(array('uid' => $_GET['prepareExamination']));
$examinationToPrepare = $statement->fetch();

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `examinees` WHERE examination = :examination");
$result = $statement->execute(array('examination' => $_GET['prepareExamination']));
$examinees = $statement->fetchAll();

$i = 1;

function mergePDF($template, $fields, $outfilename) {
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" . basename($outfilename) . "");
    $pdf = new FPDM($template);
    $pdf->Load($fields, true);
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output($outfilename, "F")
}


foreach ($examinees as $examinee => $data) {
    if ($examinationToPrepare['department'] == 1) {
        $examiner1Name = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'FirstExaminer'], 'firstName')) . ' ' . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'FirstExaminer'], 'lastName'));
        $examiner1Description = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'FirstExaminer'], 'graduation')) . "\n" . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'FirstExaminer'], 'function'));
        $examiner2Name = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'SecondExaminer'], 'firstName')) . ' ' . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'SecondExaminer'], 'lastName'));
        $examiner2Description = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'SecondExaminer'], 'graduation')) . "\n" . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['group' . strval(intval($data['subDepartment']) - 1) . 'SecondExaminer'], 'function'));
    } else {
        $examiner1Name = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['firstExaminer'], 'firstName')) . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['firstExaminer'], 'lastName'));
        $examiner1Description = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['firstExaminer'], 'graduation')) . '\n' . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['firstExaminer'], 'function'));
        $examiner2Name = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['secondExaminer'], 'firstName')) . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['secondExaminer'], 'lastName'));
        $examiner2Description = utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['secondExaminer'], 'graduation')) . '\n' . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['examiners'], $examinationToPrepare['secondExaminer'], 'function'));            
    }
    $fields = array(
        'name' => utf8_encode($data['firstName']) . ' ' . utf8_encode($data['lastName']),
        'graduierung' => utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['graduations'], $data['graduation'], 'name')) . ' ' . utf8_encode(findByUid($_SESSION['systems'], $data['system'], 'name')),
        'ort' => utf8_encode($examinationToPrepare['location']),
        'registrierung' => utf8_encode($examinationToPrepare['registration']),
        'datum' => utf8_encode($examinationToPrepare['date']),
        'pruefer1' => $examiner1Name,
        'pruefer1-grad' => $examiner1Description,
        'pruefer2' => $examiner2Name,
        'pruefer2-grad' => $examiner2Description
    );

    if (!file_exists('documents/' . utf8_encode($examinationToPrepare['title']))) {
        mkdir('documents/' . utf8_encode($examinationToPrepare['title']), 0777, true);
    }
    if ($examinationToPrepare['department'] == 1 && !file_exists('documents/' . $examinationToPrepare['title'] . '/' . findById($_SESSION['subDepartments'], $data['subDepartment'], 'name'))) {
        mkdir('documents/' . $examinationToPrepare['title'] . '/' . findById($_SESSION['subDepartments'], $data['subDepartment'], 'name'), 0777, true);
    }

    mergePDF('pdf/Urkunde1.pdf', $fields, 'documents/' . $examinationToPrepare['title'] . '/' . ($examinationToPrepare['department'] == 1 ? findById($_SESSION['subDepartments'], $data['subDepartment'], 'name') . '/' : '') . utf8_encode($data['firstName']) . ' ' . utf8_encode($data['lastName']). '.pdf');

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you should not be  be outputting in the loop. you can only send one file to the browser like this, so you need to either merge the pdf's at the end or stick them all in a container like a zip

Comment: Thanks fpr quick answer. Even if I just save the files without downloading I have the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: i dont see anything obvious, with loops its usually because your concatenating or not using 'fresh' data through each iteration. but i dont see that here. I would open one of the bad files in a text editor, look at the top and bottom for erroneous data

Comment: I couldn't find some fails in the PDFs. I did a work around now: I changed the foreach to a iterative AJAX call on client and generate only one file per request. It's not the very best but it works properly and I get immediately feedback from every file generation.

Comment: In the PHP loop, it will not work but if you try in a loop calling AJAX multiple times then it works, its working in my WordPress site.